# What do you think?

Tags: questions

> I think of this place as my home. ([OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/think))

Consulting the sentence above, can I make an interrogative as these?: 
[a] As what do you think of this place?
[b] What do you think of this place as?

Or is this alone, *what do you think of this place*, possible? Or none?

Comment: *What do you think of this place **to be***?

Comment: _How do you think of this place?_ or _How do you feel about this place?_

Comment: I think both are correct grammatically, but the first sounds very strange (I am a native AmE speaker). The second is correct. *What do you think of this place* sounds natural, but invites responses outside of your consulted sentence (I think it's great! Big! Too ostentatious! etc.) Having said that, I would probably choose to reword my sentence: How do you think of this place? What do you consider this place to be? Of what sentimental value is this place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't normally include "as":

> What do you think of this place?

The answer to the question would include the "as":

> I think of this place as my home.

You could ask about that specifically:

> Do you think of this place as your home?

And you could technically get away with:

> What do you think of this place as?

But it is informal and not highly recommended.